# Is there a difference between -b and -B when switching to a new git branch?

Tags: github, gitlab, git

This is probably a very minor thing to ask. I noticed someone on the internet typing `-B` instead of `-b` when switching to a new branch.

```
git checkout -B new_branch
```

What are the implications and when do we use the capital B. 
In case of `-D` we force the deletion with capital D flag. What happens with with capital B.

```
Force deletion:
git branch -D local_branch
```

I tried looking at these awesome [git Flight Rules](https://github.com/k88hudson/git-flight-rules) but didn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seriously, please consult the [git reference](https://git-scm.com/docs) before asking. It can also be found among other helpful links in the [git tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info)

Comment: Yes, especially with command arguments or flags, using `man` pages, `--help` or the documentation will answer >90% of such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`git checkout --help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt):

```
git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
           Specifying -b causes a new branch to be created as if git-branch(1) were called
           and then checked out. In this case you can use the --track or --no-track
           options, which will be passed to git branch. As a convenience, --track without
           -b implies branch creation; see the description of --track below.

           If -B is given, <new_branch> is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is
           reset.
```